# Function that returns an array

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to get an array to return from a function I call but the return optionArray in the below code give me a "Use of unresolved identifier optionArray.

```
public func getAdminSites(){

    let getSiteData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "adminSites")
    if getSiteData != nil
    {
        do {
            guard let sitesData = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(getSiteData as! Data) as? [ModelSites] else {
               fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't get Array")
            }
            var optionArray = ["All sites"]
            for i in 0...sitesData.count-1 {
                optionArray.append(sitesData[i].name)
            }

        } catch {
            fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
        }
    }

    return optionArray
}
```

Comment: You declared it in a to narrow scope, move the declaration of the array so it is the first line in the function. And also your function isn’t declared o return something

Comment: What do you want to return if `getSiteData` is nil?

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors:

- Function definition is missing a return type
- OptionArray (stored variable) is declared in a control flow `if` scope and not accessible on a function body level

> When you define a function, you can optionally define one or more
>   named, typed values that the function takes as input, known as
>   parameters. *You can also optionally define a type of value that the
>   function will pass back as output when it is done, known as its return
>   type*.
>   [source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

---

Fixed code:

```
public func getAdminSites() -> [String] {

    let getSiteData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "adminSites")
    var optionArray = [String]()
    if getSiteData != nil
    {
        do {
            guard let sitesData = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(getSiteData as! Data) as? [ModelSites] else {
               fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't get Array")
            }
            optionArray = ["All sites"]
            for i in 0...sitesData.count-1 {
                optionArray.append(sitesData[i].name)
            }

        } catch {
            fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
        }
    }

    return optionArray
}
```